# MacOS Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, libraries, mediapipe

```
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import cv2

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    
    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img
    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        return lmList
```

hello everyone, I write a finger counter on MacOS operating system but there is a problem when I import the **mediapipe** library, what is the problem? The error is below:

```
Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x11ae2e538) and /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_videoio.3.4.16.dylib (0x11c630860). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[38374]: Class CVWindow is implemented in both /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x11ae2e588) and /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x118ea8a68). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[38374]: Class CVView is implemented in both /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x11ae2e5b0) and /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x118ea8a90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[38374]: Class CVSlider is implemented in both /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x11ae2e5d8) and /Users/aliyazici/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x118ea8ab8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Please help me, thank you for responses.

It shouldn't give any error.

Comment: Looks like `mediapipe` also uses OpenCV, but a different version than the main one you installed in Python. Resolving that might require rebuilding both, but I can't really help you there, i'm not familiar with MacOS.